# Error when getting image from weather api. iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, weather-api

This is from debug.

```
url String  "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/Optional(\50n\).png"
```

The problem is in this line:

```
 self.imgURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(self.dodatek).png"
```

When I change (self.dodatek) for  example to icon 50n it works and show me the icon.
When I start my weather app and write name of the city I want to have url like this, but for 50n it has to be my variable that is taken from json.

```
https://openweathermap.org/img/w/50n.png
```

Comment: None of that code except for `let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)` is relevant to determine the problem. What is the value of the string `url`?  Use the debugger!

Comment: The mostly problem is string is empty or invalid URL format

Comment: I update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the quick and dirty fix for your problem is unwrapping the optional `dodatek`(which is probably `String?`) like this

```
 self.imgURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(self.dodatek!).png"
```

The cleaner solution is definitely

```
guard let dodatek = self.dodatek else {
    // handle that dodatek is nil
    // or just return
    return
}
 self.imgURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(dodatek).png"
```

#### Explanation

The problem is that your property `dodatek` can theoretically be `nil` when you declare it as `String?`
If you are sure that it can never be `nil`, declare it as

```
var dodatek: String // not String?
```

instead.
In case it can be nil, the `guard let` statement above should be used to either define a fallback value of an url that should be used (like a url to a generic weather icon maybe)